# C# - Append color code before HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, html-agility-pack

I have a html color code reader that takes in a html (in string form) like this:

```
var str = @"<html><head><title> HTML highlight test page </title>   </head>   <body>   This is text in the body.<br><h1> This is a heading </h1><p> This is a paragraph.</p>   There is more text in the body after the paragraph. <p> So is this.</p>   </body>   </html>";
```

I would like to for example, take all the `<p>` tags and append `\color[DARKGRAY]`to it

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

to

```
\color[DARKGRAY]<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

I have the HTML agility pack like this

```
var html = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
            if (html != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode item in html)
                {
                    item.Name = "\color[RED]<p>";
                }
            }
```

But that is really wrong. How can i achieve the append?

Answer (score 1):

You already have selected the paragraph nodes, then in your loop use `InsertBefore` to add the text.

```
item.ParentNode.InsertBefore(doc.CreateTextNode(@"\color[RED]"), item);
```